# Docker in WSL 2 and Integration with Visual Studio

Tags: docker, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, wsl-2

The desktop docker for windows will have a free and paid tier. In this case of the paid version, I'm trying to run visual studio professional with docker engine on wsl 2.
Is it possible?

I managed to install and run the docker engine on Wsl 2 as follows:

1. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on wsl2
2. I installed the packages in the order below with the command

sudo dpkg -i packageName

- containerd.io_1.4.9-1_amd64.deb
- docker-ce-cli_20.10.9_3-0_ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb
- docker-ce_20.10.9_3-0_ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb

Link Files Source: [packages docker ce ubuntu](https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/)

then I just worked with the commands below

sudo /etc/init.d/docker start

sudo /etc/init.d/docker stop

In the scenario with the desktop docker, the VS2019 already makes the automatic integration. And with this scenario or something alternative without the desktop docker?